# Start a browser intent in onPostExecute() method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

In the main activity:

```
download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ThreadProcess threadProcess = new ThreadProcess();
                threadProcess.execute();
```

In the ThreadProcess class (`extends` AsyncTask), I am overriding the method `onPostExecute()` to start a browser intent. I am unable to do this. Please help.

Comment: Add `ThreadProcess` implementation and eror log

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    String url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
```

Comment: The problem is that `ThreadProcess` has been defined in another Java file, not in the same as the MainActivity. Thanks.

Comment: Create a constructor in ThreadProcess that accepts Context as argument and pass it from your MainActivity. Then in onPostExecute, you can call context.startActivity(browserIntent)

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent openWebsite = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("www.myWebsite.com")); //Insert website.
                startActivity(openWebsite);
            }
        });
```